# Java - how to implement an interface properly

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and especially the abstract classes and interfaces syntax.

I have the following code:

```
public class JavaTestsHomework1 {

    public interface Comparable{
        public int compareTo();
    }

    abstract class Int implements Comparable{
        private int x;
        public Int(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
        public int compareTo(Int other) {
            return x - other.x;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

My question is: How can I implement interface `Comparable` in such a way that the `compareTo()` method returns the result of `x - other.x`?

Do I need to call a method somewhere in the `main()` ?

An in-depth,easy-to-understand explanation for a beginner would be great. I've scoured the Internet for an answer but no luck...at least nothing I can understand.

Comment: FYI, there is [already a `Comparable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Yours doesn't not make sense. Your `compareTo()` takes no arguments, so what will you be comparing to? The `java.lang.Comparable` is also generic, so you can state what type of object your class is comparable to.

Comment: There's already a class called `Comparable` in the Java library. Why would you reimplement it and give it the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your custom class comparable, you should use the one that already exists in the Java library, i.e. `java.lang.Comparable`. It's not a good idea to reimplement Java classes with the same name, it's a source of error and confusion.

Instead, you should use the one that's already there:

```
import java.lang.Comparable;
abstract class Int implements Comparable<Int> {
    private int x;
    public Int(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Int other) {
        return x - other.x;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(x);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it either explicitly

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Int i1 = new Int(2){}; // creation of anonymous class with empty class declaration body
    Int i2 = new Int(5){};
    System.out.println(i1.compareTo(i2)); // returns -3
}
```

Or Java uses it behind the curtains when you're creating some sort of collection:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.List<Int> ints = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    ints.add(new Int(3){});
    ints.add(new Int(1){});
    ints.add(new Int(2){});
    java.util.Collections.sort(ints); // Uses compareTo
    System.out.println(ints); // Will print [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for causing confusion by reimplementing `Comparable` but as I told you I'm a complete newbie in the language and I've been told I have to learn how abstract classes and interfaces work fast. Thank you for the fast answer!

Comment: Where am I supposed to use `Int i1 = new Int(2);
Int i2 = new Int(5);
System.out.println(i1.compareTo(i2)); // returns -3` this block of code? I thought abstract classes could not be instantiated

Comment: Ah right, it's abstract. Well you actually **can**, but only if you implement all abstract methods *in-place* (Have a look at [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)). You have two choices here. Either add curly braces after the instatiation or remove `abstract` from `Int`, since there's nothing that needs to be abstract here. Anyways, I've edited my code accordingly.

Comment: Actually three choices. You could create a non-`abstract` class that extends from `Int` and use that instead.

Comment: I just back home and tested the code...it doesn't want to compile. `Int i1 = new Int(2);  
    Int i2 = new Int(5);` give the error:  Uncompilable source code - non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context. I tried this by removing the `abstract` keyword from `class Int implements Comparable<Int>`

Comment: Ah this might be, because `Int` is an *inner class* of `JavaTestsHomework1`. Having it in a separate file should fix this.